# Junit: how to know which structural units are not covered in test coverage?

Tags: automated-testing, java, junit

I am currently working on running junit tests in Evosuite. Whenever I execute a test case, the structural coverage is not 100%, but around 90% or 85%. Is there a better way to know which **structural units are not covered by the evosuite**? Here I am sharing a screenshot of the output as given by evosuite.

[image: Screenshot]

You can provide any relevant info on how to know which **strucutural units of the source code** were not covered?
Any tool which may help to detect such behavior can also be specified?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite hard—and most of the time [not worth the effort](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestCoverage.html)—to reach 100% code coverage, especially for a test generator.

However, you could use a tool such as [EclEmma](https://www.eclemma.org/) to run your generated test suites and then see which parts of the code are not covered. You will get a report similar to this:

[image]